# ¿Como mostrar hora local con PHP?

Tags: php, html, html5, aplicación-web

Intente con el siguiente script:

```
<?php
$hora = date("G:a");
echo $hora;
?>
```

Seleccione el formato G para imprimir la hora sin los 0 iniciales, pero me imprime 14:pm y en mi ordenador son las 11:am, ¿Como sincronizo php con mi hora local?

Comment: ¿Qué hora local quieres? ¿La del servidor o la del ordenador del cliente de tu aplicación?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Debes agregar tu huso horario al momento de mostrar la fecha (o antes), hay varias formas de hacerlo, una de estas es con [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php):

```
$hora = new DateTime("now", new DateTimeZone('America/New York'));
echo $hora->format('G');
```

También podrías usar [date_default_timezone_set](http://php.net/manual/es/function.date-default-timezone-set.php) :

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New York");
echo date('G');
```

Comment: Gracias shaz, solucionaste mi problema, mil gracias!!!

Comment: De ser así, puedes marcar la respuesta como aceptada.

Comment: Ya lo hice, no entiendo mucho stackoverflow, perdón

Answer (score 2):

Si solo quieres mostrar la hora de tu server, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
  echo date('h:i:s A');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes intentar con lo siguiente;

```
<?php 
$fecha = new DateTime('2000-01-01', new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Nauru'));
echo $fecha->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
$fecha->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Pacific/Chatham'));
echo $fecha->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') . "\n";
?>
```

Información que se obtuvo de la documentación oficial de PHP http://php.net/manual/es/datetime.settimezone.php