# Hora Actual PHP

Tags: php

Tengo un type de timo time pero no consigo me de la hora actual o la local de mi equipo, mi código es el siguiente:

```
<input class="dimension" style="float: left;" type="time" name="hora" value="
<?php 
print_r(localtime());
?>">
```

Comment: revisa esta parte: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/13383/91549

Comment: Proba con **[date()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.date.php)**

Comment: o `<input type="text" value="<?php echo date("h:i:s A", strtotime("- 1 minute"));?>">`

Comment: hola, podrías agregarle lo que es **date_default_timezone_set();** para definir tu zona horaria, quizas por eso no te sale bien la hora. saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo lo haria con la siguiente instrucción

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s")."\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP tiene varias funciones para datos temporales y cuenta con la clase `DateTime`, que tiene una flexibilidad interesante.

En tu caso usaría esta clase.

```
$mDate=new DateTime();
$hoy=$mDate->format("H:i:s");
```

Y para mostrarlo en el `input`:

```
<input class="dimension" style="float: left;" type="time" name="hora" value="<?php $hoy; ?>">
```

Aquí en `$mDate` tendrías un objeto `DateTime` completo y puedes usar `format` para representarlo de la forma que necesites, cambiar la zona horaria, etc.

Si lo miramos por dentro:

```
var_dump($mDate);
```

Veremos algo así:

```
object(DateTime)#4 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2019-03-28 19:55:40.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(13) "Europe/Berlin"
}
```

Ten en cuenta que PHP trabaja en el servidor, y puede que la zona horaria del servidor no sea la de tu equipo local. En ese caso, puedes setear otra zona horaria a tu objeto (esto es particularmente útil cuando no se requiere cambiar la zona horaria del servidor).

```
$mDate->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/Denver'));
```

O bien directamente al crear el objeto:

```
$mDate = new DateTime('now', new DateTimeZone('America/Denver));
```

El objeto se verá ahora así:

```
object(DateTime)#4 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2019-03-28 13:03:02.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(14) "America/Denver"
}
```

Comment: a todos. Se logro con el siguiente código para aquellos que tengan una necesidad similar: <input class="dimension" style="float: left;" type="text" name="hora" value="<?php date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_city'); echo date("h:i:s A");?>">