# Sumar horas de diferencia horaria a una hora UTC

Tags: php

Tengo una pregunta. Tengo esta hora:

```
2019-12-03UTC01:15:00
```

Pero mi hora local tiene 4:30 horas de diferencia de esa. Quiero sumarle la diferencia que hay entre mi zona horaria y esa hora. En si la hora deberia quedar en 21:15:00.

He intentado con esto:

```
$hora = "2019-12-03T01:15:00";
echo date($hora, (strtotime ("-4 Hours")));
```

Pero lamentablemente no me esta funcionando. Por favor ayudenme!

Comment: [En esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13382/como-mostrar-hora-local-con-php) puedes encontrar una posible solución.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [¿Como mostrar hora local con PHP?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13382/como-mostrar-hora-local-con-php)

Answer (score 0):

```
$hora_actual=date("H:i"); #Obtienes la hora de tu servidor, OJO depende de tu servidor más no del país en el que tu estés 
$hora = "2019-12-03T01:15:00"; #La hora que especificas
$resultado=date("H:i:s",strtotime("00:00") + strtotime($hora) - strtotime($hora_actual) ); #realizas la diferencia de zona horaria.
echo $resultado;
```